# Questions about new initiative mechanics for an RPG

Tags: game-design, initiative

I'm designing a new tabletop RPG. I've got an idea for how to handle battle initiative and am looking for feedback and if it sounds reasonable/workable.

- Each character has 6 stats: Strength, Conviction, Sanity, Dexterity, Intelligence, Charisma, Perception
- Each character sheet has a wheel with 10 slices on it (like a pie chart), numbered 1-10 with the 1 slot highlighted.
- For each round of battle, players will roll a d20 and add their Dexterity and level. (*At Level 2 with Dex 4, the player adds 6 to their roll*)
- The player then moves a marker/pencil/anything they want, around the initiative wheel that number of spaces. Using the previous stats example if the player rolls a 2 they move 8 spaces around the circle. (*Level 2 + Dex 4 + Roll 2 = 8 spaces*)
- If you land on or pass '1' on the wheel, you earn an action. If you pass it twice, you earn an action and an interrupt to use that round. (Essentially 2 actions)
- If more than one player/NPC earns an action, whoever landed on the highest number on the wheel goes first. If that is tied, it goes to whoever has the highest initiative modifier. If that's tied, roll a d20 until someone rolls higher. (Or players/GM can choose who goes first)

**Here's the goals of the system over other systems:**

- Give players and NPC's a chance to act more often if they are fast enough.
- Allow the order of action to change each round, rather than using a static order set at the beginning of the battle.
- Be simple enough that players don't get frustrated with the system.

**Here's my questions:**

- Does that sound confusing? (This will hopefully end up in a book some day, so I need to write it out to be understandable on its own.)
- How can I tell if that's balanced / is it balanced?

Comment: You still have two questions: the first one is fair. The second is open to interpretation since what is fair in a setting might not be in another. You might be better served asking this sort of open ended questions on a form.

Comment: To be clear, this is pretty much roll 1d20 + modifiers and compute the total then the character gets an action for every 10 and an interrupt for every 20. Is that accurate?

Comment: @HeyICanChan If I understand correctly, the player's spot on the circle is persistent between rounds. So if they ended the previous round on 10, then a roll of 11 would get them an action and an interrupt next round. In other words, any excess in the roll counts as progress towards the next round's first action.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Close. The player doesn't necessarily have to get a full 20 to get the interrupt. If they landed on `9` the previous round and then get a `12`, for example, they could get an interrupt. Otherwise right.

Comment: “looking for feedback and if it sounds reasonable/workable” isn’t the type of question this site is for. (Hence, even if this is revised to fit the site’s mission, it will likely no longer satisfy your need for feedback.) For non-specific requests for feedback on a game design you want [a discussion forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).

Comment: "Each character has 6 stats: Strength, Conviction, Sanity, Dexterity, Intelligence, Charisma, Perception" That's 7 stats.

Comment: Related meta: [Is this the sort of place to ask about game design for my own game?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7848/is-this-the-sort-of-place-to-ask-about-game-design-for-my-own-game)